# What is this component on the Raspberry Pi 4 Model B?

Tags: hardware

Can anybody identify the chip in this section of the board? My RPi won't boot and this chip is scorching hot (over 80° according to a temp probe). I'm guessing this chip is busted. I've replaced SMDs on Macbooks before so hoping to find a replacement chip and make a similar repair here.

I found this photo online that seems to have a part number printed but the resolution isn't high enough. On my board the chip is polished with no markings.

[image: power supply?]

Comment: `80°` of what? .

Comment: how do you know that the chip is defective?

Answer (score 1):

These are inductors (part of power supply).

The fault is elsewhere (probably PMIC) although they may be part the regulated CPU supply.

Blowing up PMIC seems to be a popular pastime for Pi users.